# How to manipulate like button on Facebook web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a chrome extension and I'm trying to get it to be able to stop a like on Facebook from going through even after the like button has been clicked. In my content.js, I currently have the code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink"]').forEach(function(element) {
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var r = confirm("You clicked like");
        if (r == true) {
            alert("you clicked OK");
        } else {
            alert("you clicked Cancel")
        }           
    })
});
```

As of now, when the like button is clicked, a confirm box pops up but the like does not go through until "OK" or "Cancel" is clicked.

How do I prevent the like action from going through when the 'cancel' button is clicked? Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: How do I prevent the like action from going through when the 'cancel' button is clicked?

Comment: Add that question into your post.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It's been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the following.    
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink"]').forEach(function(element) 
 {
     element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var r = confirm("You clicked like");
        if (r == true) {
           alert("you clicked OK");
        } else {
           alert("you clicked Cancel");
           e.preventDefault();
        }           
     });
 });
```

For reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I played around with the preventDefault method, and it doesn't seem to prevent the like action from going through. The stopPropagation method does prevent the like action from going through, however it returns me to the beginning of the web page. What do you think is causing the preventDefault method to not cancel the 'click' event?

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the original function with a different function of your own.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink"]')[0].onclick = 
    e => console.log('blablabla!')

document.querySelectorAll('a[data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink"]').forEach(function(element) {
    let originalOnClick = element.onclick
    element.onclick = null
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('look ma, no hands!')
        originalOnClick(e)
    })
})
```

```html
<a href="#" data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink">Like</a>
```

I tested it on Facebook and it works there too.

Obviously you have to adapt this concept to your needs.

Comment: Content scripts run in isolated world so this approach won't work unless you show the full correct implementation - [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: It worked in the primitive form I showed - not sure if there would be issues beyond that.

Comment: Oh I see you're saying it's an extension development issue. Yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault()

Just add the parameter to your listener function

```
function(event){
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
}
```